# Migrating site from windows to linux

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I migrate site with apache, mysql, php to linux container docker.
Site load but show this:
Notice: Undefined index: content in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3

```
if($_GET['content'])  #this 3rd
        header("Location: /");
```

Can you tell me how solave this. Thanks

Comment: Well, the request URL misses `content` query-string parameter like this: `https://example.com/?content=123`. The reason it was not reported before is probably due to looser error reporting settings on the previous PHP conf.

Comment: thank you i understand, but it is not show html. php-fpm, mysql, apache in container. 3 containers and i use proxy fromapache to php-fpm. Test file work, like phpinfo, proxy work. But this site not load